# Power Bi count rows for all tables in one measure

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In my power Bi I would like to count rows for all my tables and having this output:

| Table Name | Row count |
| --- | --- |
| Table1 | 126 |
| Table2 | 985 |
| Table3 | 998 |
| ... | ... |

As long as I have few tables I can do

```
NEWTABLE = UNION(
  ROW("TableName","Table1", "Rowcount",ROWSCOUNT(Table1)),
  ROW("TableName","Table2", "Rowcount",ROWSCOUNT(Table2)),
  ...
)
```

But this starts to be complicated when I have many tables.
Is there a way I can do it? Like a loop or something?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a metrics then you can use DaxStudio -> ViewMetrics

where cardinality is your "rowCounts"

[image]

If you need something more, then you can get all table name from DMV

```
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

populate this as another table in your model, and use M language to loop through.

here useful example:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Power-query-Counting-rows-from-all-table-in-query-editor-but-not/td-p/1198489